# Is there a way to access a layout's region that was created in a ListController from a ShowController in Marionette.js?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, marionette

The App has a mainRegion, that shows a layout that is dynamic. I have a combo problem of a routing issue and accessing a layout, and updating its `pizzaTypeRegion`. This layout is created in list_controller.js.coffee, and it has a `pizzaTypeNameRegion` (holds pizza type names) and a `pizzaTypeRegion` (shows pizza type details). I'd like to update the `pizzaTypeRegion` when I manually edit the url: `http://localhost:3000/#pizza_types`. #pizza_types shows all of the pizza_types as expected.

I can click on a link in the `pizzaTypeNameRegion` and it updates the `pizzaTypeRegion` with the proper contents without any issue.

**When manually typing in the id of the pizza_type in the url:**

`http://localhost:3000/#pizza_types/1` - should show 1st pizza type, but does not update the `pizzaTypeRegion`

`http://localhost:3000/#pizza_types/2` - should show the 2nd pizza type, but does not update the `pizzaTypeRegion`

I am getting proof that the specific pizza_type is obtained via logging to the console.

**pizza_types_app.js.coffee**

```
@Pizzeria.module "PizzaTypesApp", (PizzaTypesApp, App, Backbone, Marionette,$, _) ->
  @startWithParent = false

  class PizzaTypesApp.Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
    appRoutes:
      "pizza_types" : "listPizzaTypes"
      "pizza_types/:id" : "showPizzaType"

  API =

   listPizzaTypes: ->
     PizzaTypesApp.List.Controller.listPizzaTypes()

   showPizzaType: (model) ->   
     PizzaTypesApp.Show.Controller.showPizzaTypeFromEvent model     


  App.on "pizzaTypes:show", ->
    App.navigate "pizza_types"
    API.listPizzaTypes()

  App.addInitializer ->
    new PizzaTypesApp.Router
      controller: API

  App.reqres.setHandler "show:pizza:type:view", (model) ->
    API.showPizzaType model

  App.reqres.setHandler "show:first:pizzaType:view", ->
    API.showFirstPizzaType()
```

**list_controller.js.coffee**

```
@Pizzeria.module "PizzaTypesApp.List", (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

      List.Controller =

        listPizzaTypes: ->
          pizzaTypes = App.request "get:pizza:types:entities"
          pizzaType = gon.pizza_type
          @layout = new List.Layout

          @layout.on "show", =>
            @pizzaTypeNameRegion pizzaTypes
            @pizzaTypeRegion()

          App.mainRegion.show @layout

        pizzaTypeNameRegion: (pizzaTypes) ->
          pizzaTypesNameView = new List.PizzaTypeNames
            collection: pizzaTypes
          @layout.pizzaTypeNameRegion.show pizzaTypesNameView

          pizzaTypesNameView.on "itemview:show:pizza:type", (childView, pizzaType) =>
            @newPizzaTypeRegion(pizzaType)

        pizzaTypeRegion: ->
          initialPizzaTypeView = App.request "show:first:pizzaType:view"
          @layout.pizzaTypeRegion.show initialPizzaTypeView

        newPizzaTypeRegion: (pizzaType) ->
          newPizzaTypeView = App.request "show:pizza:type:view", pizzaType.id
          @layout.pizzaTypeRegion.show newPizzaTypeView
```

**show_controller.js.coffee**

```
@Pizzeria.module "PizzaTypesApp.Show", (Show, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  Show.Controller =

    showPizzaTypeFromEvent: (model) ->
      pizzaType = App.request "pizzaType:entity", model
      pizzaTypeView = new Show.PizzaType
        model: pizzaType
      App.mainRegion.show pizzaTypeView  
      # mainRegion is updated with whatever the url is 
      # ex)`http://localhost:3000/#pizza_types/2` will 
      # place the pizza_type with the id of 2 in the 
      # App's mainRegion, breaking the layout that I 
      # set up in the list_controller.js.coffee. Browser back and forward
      # buttons work, but layout is broken, missing other regions (and their info)
```

How do I update the `pizzaTypeRegion` with the new pizza type? Is there a way to access the layout instance that was created in list_controller so just the `pizzaTypeRegion` is updated with the new contents, not affecting the other regions in the layout by manually typing in the URL?

** **EDIT** **

- I got rid of the above code and placed everything back so separation
  of concerns could be maintained. I did not end up using a global, but
  rather the event bus

:

list_controller:

```
newPizzaTypeRegion: (pizzaType) ->
  id = pizzaType.id
  App.vent.on "new:pizza:type:for:pizza:type:region", (pizzaTypeView) =>
    @layout.pizzaTypeRegion.show pizzaTypeView
```

show_controller:

```
showPizzaTypeFromEvent: (id) ->
  pizzaType = App.request "pizzaType:entity", id
  pizzaTypeView = new Show.PizzaType
    model: pizzaType
  App.vent.trigger "new:pizza:type:for:pizza:type:region", pizzaTypeView
```

List.Controller knows how to update itself, Show.Controller tells List.Controller the content to update with. Works great, so much cleaner and it's decoupled.

Comment: I need to figure out a way to attach the layout to a global object, or pass it in the route event. Any ideas on the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give a good answer since it depends on the specific instance. Basically you have 2 options:

- attaching the layout somewhere accessible (doesn't necessarily ahve to be global, it can e.g. be at the sub-application level)
- using events to react to modifications and update your layout/view

Another thing to investigate if you're using this layout in multiple views, is to instantiate it within the sub-application's initializer and attach it somewhere (e.g. the sub-app) so it can be accessed from multiple controllers.

Comment: once again thank you for your answer, I hope to be able to repay you one day. 

I posted my code below. It works but I'm not sure if this is an anti-pattern due to lack of experience in JS (been coding with it for only about 7 months). 

Any general advice on this solution? This seems to blur the separation of concerns, but is there an alternative? I don't know because of JS's scoping. Make sense to place at higher level in app so can be referenced.

Would using events allow the specific layout instance's regions to be accessible without the moving of view code around?

Comment: I got rid of the above code and placed everything back so separation of concerns could be maintained. I did not end up using a global, but rather the event bus.

Answer (score 0):

**In my pizza_types_app.js.coffee submodule:**

```
@Pizzeria.module "PizzaTypesApp", (PizzaTypesApp, App, Backbone, Marionette,$, _) ->
  @startWithParent = false

  # took this out of the list_view    
  class PizzaTypeName extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
    template: "pizza_types/list/templates/_pizza_type_name"
    modelEvents:
      "change" : "render"

    events:
      "click a" : "showPizzaType"

    showPizzaType: (event) ->
      @trigger "show:pizza:type", @model
      @model     

  class PizzaTypeNames extends Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView
    template: "pizza_types/list/templates/pizza_type_names"
    itemView: PizzaTypeName

  # took this out of the list_view 
  class DefaultLayout extends Backbone.Marionette.Layout
    template: "pizza_types/list/templates/pizza_types_layout"
    regions:
      pizzaTypeNameRegion : "#pizza-type-name-region"
      pizzaTypeRegion : "#pizza-type-region"

  App.addInitializer ->
    @layout = new DefaultLayout
    Pizzeria.PizzaTypesApp.layout = @layout
    App.mainRegion.show @layout

    @layout.on "show", =>
      pizzaTypes = App.request "get:pizza:types:entities"   
      pizzaTypesNameView = new PizzaTypeNames
        collection: pizzaTypes

      @layout.pizzaTypeNameRegion.show pizzaTypesNameView 
      @layout.pizzaTypeRegion

  class PizzaTypesApp.Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
    appRoutes:
      "pizza_types" : "listPizzaTypes"
      "pizza_types/:id" : "showPizzaType"


  API =

   listPizzaTypes: ->
     PizzaTypesApp.List.Controller.listPizzaTypes()

   showPizzaType: (id) ->   
     PizzaTypesApp.Show.Controller.showPizzaTypeFromEvent id

   showFirstPizzaType: ->
     PizzaTypesApp.Show.Controller.showFirstPizzaType()

  App.on "pizzaTypes:show", ->
    App.navigate "pizza_types"
    API.listPizzaTypes()

  App.addInitializer ->
    new PizzaTypesApp.Router
      controller: API

  App.reqres.setHandler "show:pizza:type:view", (model) ->
    API.showPizzaType model

  App.reqres.setHandler "show:first:pizzaType:view", ->
    API.showFirstPizzaType()
```

**show_controller.js.coffee**

```
@Pizzeria.module "PizzaTypesApp.Show", (Show, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  Show.Controller =

    showPizzaTypeFromEvent: (id) ->
      pizzaType = App.request "pizzaType:entity", id
      pizzaTypeView = new Show.PizzaType
        model: pizzaType
      pizzaTypeView

      @layout = Pizzeria.PizzaTypesApp.layout
      App.mainRegion.show @layout
      @layout.pizzaTypeRegion.show pizzaTypeView
```

**list_controller.coffee.js**

```
@Pizzeria.module "PizzaTypesApp.List", (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  List.Controller =

    listPizzaTypes: ->
      pizzaTypes = App.request "get:pizza:types:entities"
      pizzaType = gon.pizza_type
      @layout = Pizzeria.PizzaTypesApp.layout #new List.Layout

      @layout.on "show", =>
        @pizzaTypeRegion()

      App.mainRegion.show @layout

    pizzaTypeNameRegion: (pizzaTypes) ->
      pizzaTypesNameView = new List.PizzaTypeNames
        collection: pizzaTypes
      @layout.pizzaTypeNameRegion.show pizzaTypesNameView

      pizzaTypesNameView.on "itemview:show:pizza:type", (childView, pizzaType) =>
        @newPizzaTypeRegion(pizzaType)

    pizzaTypeRegion: ->
      initialPizzaTypeView = App.request "show:first:pizzaType:view"
      @layout.pizzaTypeRegion.show initialPizzaTypeView

    newPizzaTypeRegion: (pizzaType) ->
      newPizzaTypeView = App.request "show:pizza:type:view", pizzaType.id
      @layout.pizzaTypeRegion.show newPizzaTypeView


    getPizzaTypeNameView: (pizzaTypes) ->
      new List.PizzaTypeNames
        collection: pizzaTypes

    getPizzaTypeLayout: ->
      new List.Layout
```